# Segmentation fault (core dumped) case with fread

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Would some please tell me why this code leads to such an error?

```
unsigned char buffer;
fread(&buffer,1,1,image_ptr);
printf("%s ",buffer);
```

The image is 8-bit grayscale. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`%s` is the format specifier to print a string, but `buffer` is not a string.  That causes undefined behaviour.  You want `%c` or maybe `%u` or `%x` depending on what you want as output.

Answer (score 5):

The `%s` specifier is for strings i.e. a `char *`, you're passing a `char`, which isn't the same.

Use `%c` in `printf` to print `buffer`:

```
printf("%c ", buffer);
```

Comment: `%c` doesn't seem to make sense given the context of "the image is 8-bit grayscale".

Comment: Two comments - `unsigned char` seems a much more appropriate type here than plain old `char`. And `%02X` seems like a much more appropriate format string here *after* you switch to `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 3):

Because you read one byte into the buffer and treat it as an 0-terminated string in printf. This will interpret the memory at @buffer as a pointer to char (on most modern machines 4 or 8 bytes long) and then print bytes starting at that memory address until a 0 is found.

This way you tell printf to

- first read 3-7 bytes behind the variable buffer
- and the read bytes from a completely random memory address

Accessing memory you do not own is undefined behaviour, often honored with segmentation fault.

Comment: This answer is just plain wrong: there is no access to "memory behind buffer" here.

Comment: @Employed Russian: my answer is plain wrong: true. But there is access to memory behind buffer here. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

replace %s with %c ..
%c is for single character
%s is for a string (more than 1 charachter)